# Display checked checkbox if the value is saved in database

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I'm currently working on displaying checked checkbox if its saved in database.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('Select * from productsizes a, sizestops b WHERE 
a.productinformationID = :prodID AND a.sizeID = b.sizestopsID ');

    $stmt->bindParam(':prodID', $productID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $couunterer = $stmt->rowCount();
    $y= 1;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   

    if($y != $couunterer)
    {
    echo  $sizes5 = $row['sizetopsName']." ";  
    }
    elseif($y == $couunterer)
    {
    echo $sizes5 = $row['sizetopsName']." ";  
    }

    $y++;
    }
```

This display my saved sizes for example XSMALL and LARGE

and this is my codes to display all checkbox from other table

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sizestops order by sizestopsID ASC");
$statement->execute();

while($rows2 = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo "
<label style=' display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;'>

<input type='checkbox' name='sizes[]' class='checkbox' id='sizesprod' onchange='checksize()' value='" .$rows2['sizestopsID']. "'". $pre_checked.">".$rows2['sizetopsName']."
</label>";

}
```

This display all the sizes from

```
XSMALL, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, XLARGE, XXLARGE, FREES SIZE
```

Now i want to display checked to checkbox XSMALL and LARGE only and the rest is not checked. How can i do that?
Hopefully any one can help me with this thanks!

PHP and Javascript will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your `tables structure` it's a little hard to write a query, but generally you can write a query and `join` these two tables and then check if a field from second table is not empty, then it means there is a correspondent record in the second table so you have to check the `checkbox`, else if it was empty then the `checkbox` should not be checked...

the query will be something like this:

```
SELECT sizestops.sizestopsID, sizetopsName.sizestops, productsizes.productinformationID
FROM sizestops
LEFT JOIN productsizes
ON sizestops.sizestopsID = productsizes.sizeID 
ORDER BY sizestops.sizestopsID ASC
```

now in your loop you can check if `productinformationID` is empty or not like this:

```
<?php
while($rows2 = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $pre_checked = empty($row2['productinformationID']) ? '' : ' checked';

    echo "
    <label style=' display:inline-block;
            width:150px;
            height:50px;
            margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
            vertical-align:middle;'>

    <input type='checkbox' name='sizes[]' class='checkbox' id='sizesprod' onchange='checksize()' value='".$rows2['sizestopsID']. "'". $pre_checked.">".$rows2['sizetopsName']."
    </label>";
}
?>
```

This should do the job for you

Comment: It only displays the 2 sizes that is saved in database which are XSMALL and LARGE the other checkboxes is not appearing. The other should appear too without check in checkbox.

Comment: Did you used to exact query I posted or changed it?

Comment: I used it exactly and i changed it

Comment: OK, can you please share how did you change the query?